# Pandas Pivot, Unstack or otherwise transform column to headers with proper count

Tags: pandas, pivot, pandas-groupby, pivot-table, reshape

My sample data:

```
          Division    Region     Director    Month
   0      1           A          Smith       JAN
   1      1           B          Jones       JAN
   2      2           C          Williams    FEB
   3      3           D          Johnson     FEB
   4      1           B          Watkins     MAR
```

The desired intermediate output is:

```
Division    Region     Director    JAN   FEB   MAR
1           A          Smith       1      0     0
1           B          Jones       1      0     0
2           C          Williams    0      1     0
3           D          Johnson     0      1     0
1           B          Watkins     0      0     1
```

The final output, ideally:

```
Division    Region     Director    JAN   FEB   MAR
1           A          Smith       1      0     0
            B          Jones       1      0     0
                       Watkins     0      0     1
2           C          Williams    0      1     0
3           D          Johnson     0      1     0
```

I have tried pivot, pivotable, unstack and various groupby combos found on SS and elsewhere.  Nothing quite gets me to what I need in the intermediate or final version.  Ultimately, I will be saving this to an excel file for the end user once I can get Pandas to help get it into the shape I need. Thanks for taking a moment to check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pivot` and assign a dummy value to have a `values`

```
>>> df.assign(value=1) \
      .pivot(index=['Division', 'Region', 'Director'], 
             columns='Month', values='value') \
      .fillna(0).astype(int)[df['Month'].unique()] \
      .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()

   Division Region  Director  JAN  FEB  MAR
0         1      A     Smith    1    0    0
1         1      B     Jones    1    0    0
2         1      B   Watkins    0    0    1
3         2      C  Williams    0    1    0
4         3      D   Johnson    0    1    0
```

**Update**

> I get the following error (which one of my other attempts brought the same error message). Value error: index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Use `pivot_table` rather than `pivot`:

```
>>> df.assign(value=1) \
      .pivot_table(index=['Division', 'Region', 'Director'],
                   columns='Month', values='value', aggfunc='first') \
      .fillna(0).astype(int)[df['Month'].unique()] \
      .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you for working this out. I get the following error (which one of my other attempts brought the same error message). Value error: index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. Ideas?

Comment: You have 2 identical rows `['Division', 'Region', 'Director', 'Month']`. 2 solutions: 1. `drop_duplicates` before pivot or 2. use `pivot_table` with `aggfunc='first'`. Il will update my answer with the last one.

Comment: In the sample data all the directors names are different so which two roles are you referring to as being identical?  Do you mean after they get pivoted they turn out to be identical?

Comment: You have `ValueError` on this sample??? or in your real data?

Comment: You’re right. For the sample data, works. Thank you!  My actual  Data also has an index column Which I didn’t put in the sample data by accident.

Comment: How would I adjust the answer you gave to account for the fact that my actual data has the identical set of columns but also has an index column?

Comment: Change your sample by a real one (add your index columns and insert duplicates).

Comment: I just updated my sample data to reflect that my actual data has an index column as shown.

Comment: Sorry but your index seems to be irrelevant and you have no really duplicates. So both version `pivot`  and `pivot_table` work on your update.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for all your time and help!

Comment: I think I understood (I hope) :-) Can you check my last update please?

Answer (score 2):

Or use `pd.get_dummies`:

```
pd.concat([df.drop('Month', 1), pd.get_dummies(df.Month)], axis=1)

   Division Region  Director  FEB  JAN  MAR
0         1      A     Smith    0    1    0
1         1      B     Jones    0    1    0
2         2      C  Williams    1    0    0
3         3      D   Johnson    1    0    0
4         1      B   Watkins    0    0    1
```

For the final output, it seems you just want to `sort_values`:

```
(pd.concat([df.drop('Month', 1), pd.get_dummies(df.Month)], axis=1)
   .sort_values(['Division', 'Region']))

   Division Region  Director  FEB  JAN  MAR
0         1      A     Smith    0    1    0
1         1      B     Jones    0    1    0
4         1      B   Watkins    0    0    1
2         2      C  Williams    1    0    0
3         3      D   Johnson    1    0    0
```

Comment: Just for future reference, `get_dummies` supports the expansion of columns natively without needing to `drop` and `concat`. `pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Month'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')`

Comment: @HenryEcker Nice. Good to know that. Thanks for the comment.